# Custom UIViewController IOS4.3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ios4, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have static library and my custom view controller inside (f.e mainVC). 
My static library will be built in some third party application.

I have to show mainVC.view instantly after third app did launch.
I do:

```
[window addSubView:mainVC.view];
```

but how can I do my mainVC active? It means I have to deny landscape orientation in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and this method never calls in this case.

I've also tried to call manually

```
[self.mainVC viewWillAppear:NO];
```

but still unsuccessful.

Maybe I should use

```
-(void)presentModalViewController:animated
```

but it's deprecated. And I have to support IOS 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check if the class is allowed to respond to the method before you call it.

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) 
{
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
else
{
    //some other methods
}
```

This way you can use the deprecated method for support with IOS 4.3, and use another solution for later IOS versions

Comment: The correct way would be to use `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) [self presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:completionBlock]; else { ... }`

Comment: Noted: not as knowledgable of the 4.3 methods, so copied from his own question method. The idea remains the same if you want to have backwards compatibility

Comment: Actually it's not exactly what I need. I have to show mainVC.view like a popup (Same like FBDialog does) and if I present mainVC modally and set mainVC.view margins... It has black area around my mainVC.view